# Display PHP array as animation?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, animation

I have a php array which I displaying with a while loop and it gets the data from a sql database, at the moment everything in the array appears instantly, but would it be possible to get them to display with a half second delay? Would i have to use Javascript?

Comment: I think you can use jQuery methods like fadeIn

Comment: Do you want each element seperately displayed with a delay, or do you want the complete set to be displayed after a certain delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `<div>` around your array, like this:

```
<div id="myElementID" style="display:none;">
MY ARRAY
</div>
```

and it will not be visible. With Javascript you can make it visible after, for instance, a 1000 milliseconds, with:

```
function showElement(id)
// make hidden element visible
{
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
}

window.setTimeout("showElement('myElementID')",1000);
```

No other libraries are needed for this.

If you need to do multiple rows you can wrap a `<div>` around each row, or use the `<tr>` tag if your're using tables, like this:

```
<div id="myRow1" style="display:none;">
ROW 1
</div>
<div id="myRow2" style="display:none;">
ROW 2
</div>
<div id="myRow3" style="display:none;">
ROW 2
</div>
.......
<div id="myRowN" style="display:none;">
ROW N
</div>
```

And in your script:

```
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) { 
  window.setTimeout("showElement('myRow"+i+"')",500);
}
```

You would still need the `showElement()` function.

Comment: I think you are not answering his question. Didn't he asked for a delay between the different array elements?

Comment: You might be right. So he can use multiple `<div>`'s with id's. One for each row, and run a script to show them one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in your PHP you can call a javascript function with a timeout. Make sure you included the jQuery libary first en defined the method to call. It will be something like the code below. You can change the `$delay` variable for more or less delay between the different elements.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function makeVisible(id, delay)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){

            $('#'+id).fadeIn();

        }, delay);
    }
</script>

<?php
    $delay  = 500;
    $array  = array(1,2,3,4,5);

    $counter = 0;
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        $uniqueId = 'aClassName'.$counter;

        echo '<div style="display:none;" id="'.$uniqueId.'">'.$value.'</div>';
        echo '<script>makeVisible("'.$uniqueId.'", '.($counter++*$delay).')</script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need javaScript. Just use jQuery. Use CSS to hide the content container before the page loads and show the content (`fadeIn()`) after the desired time interval using `setTimeout()`.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tnzqv4fx/